C# (.NET 4.8) - Verify signature using Public Key
I need to verify signature of a JSON webhook. In the documentation there is only JavaScript example of how to do this:
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require('fs');

const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('publicKey.pem', 'utf-8');
const payload = fs.readFileSync('payload.json', 'utf-8');
const signature = fs.readFileSync('signature.txt', 'utf-8');

function verify(publicKey, signature, payload) {
  const verifier = crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA256");
  verifier.update(payload);

  return verifier.verify(
    { key: publicKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING },
    Buffer.from(signature, 'base64')
  );
}

const verified = verify(publicKey, signature, payload);

console.log('Signature Verified: ', verified);

The above code prints "true" in the console log. I'm trying to simulate the same in C# and it always returns false:
private static bool VerifySignature(string publicKeyPath, string payload, string signature)
{
    byte[] byteToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    byte[] bsign = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    string pemText = File.ReadAllText(publicKeyPath);
    PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(pemText));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();
    RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    cryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

    bool result = cryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(byteToSign, bsign, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    return result;
}

I tried different approaches in C#, the above one looks cleaner and shorter than the other ones. What am I doing wrong? Please note that I use .NET 4.8, so I don't have methods like RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportFromPem that are available only from version 5. Thanks
UPDATE - This code works properly:
private static bool VerifySignature(string publicKeyPath, string payload, string signature)
{
    byte[] byteToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    byte[] bsign = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    string pemText = File.ReadAllText(publicKeyPath);
    PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(pemText));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();

    PssSigner pssSigner = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha256Digest(), bsign.Length - 32 - 2);
    pssSigner.Init(false, publicKey);
    pssSigner.BlockUpdate(byteToSign, 0, byteToSign.Length);
    bool result = pssSigner.VerifySignature(bsign);

    return result;
}


You are using different paddings, PSS in the NodeJS code and PKCS#1 v1.5 in the C# code. For compatibility, the paddings must be identical. In the C# code, try RSASignaturePadding.Pss.

@Topaco When I use RSASignaturePadding.Pss then cryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData returns an error: "Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm"

Apply RSACng (or use BouncyCastle on platforms/environments where there is no provider that supports PSS).

@Topaco RSACng didn't work either. It didn't through an exception like in case of RSACryptoServiceProvider, but returned false. I've updated my initial question with working code using PssSigner - please see above

If you have found a solution - it seems to be the BC approach - you should not post it in the question, but in an answer!

The incompatibility of the native C# implementation (with RSACng) is probably due to the fact that, according to the documentation, NodeJS uses the maximum salt length for PSS by default, while C# uses the output size of the digest, which is more common. Since the salt length is not configurable in native C#, but it is in NodeJS, this incompatibility can only be solved by adapting the NodeJS code (or by using BC, which allows the salt length to be configured).

This code works properly:
private static bool VerifySignature(string publicKeyPath, string payload, string signature)
{
    byte[] byteToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    byte[] bsign = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    string pemText = File.ReadAllText(publicKeyPath);
    PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(pemText));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();

    PssSigner pssSigner = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha256Digest(), bsign.Length - 32 - 2);
    pssSigner.Init(false, publicKey);
    pssSigner.BlockUpdate(byteToSign, 0, byteToSign.Length);
    bool result = pssSigner.VerifySignature(bsign);

    return result;
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
